# Function isn't working with a gobal variable. Should it be expected?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables, local-variables

As title says, I can't have the variable "countDash" being used on my function if it's globaly, only local. Should it be like this?

What am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

```
//count
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el");
let count = 0;

//message to user
let username = "Mr. Unknown";
let message = "You have three new notifications";
let messageToUser = `${message}, ${username}!`;

//welcome message
let welcomeEl = document.getElementById("welcome-el");
let name = "Eduardo";
let greeting = "Welcome back";
welcomeEl.innerHTML = `${greeting}, ${name}!`;

function increment() {
    count += 1;
    countEl.innerHTML = count;
}

// let countDash = ` ${count} -`; //does not work
function save() {
    let countDash = ` ${count} -`; //it only works if I have it here localy
    saveEl.innerHTML += countDash;
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* does "does not work" mean? Does anything happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: You should add more details

Answer (score -1):

When you declare CountDash in the global scope, the code is only being run once, so CountDash is initialised with the value ' 0 - '. So even when you update count in your increment function, countDash will not be updated. If you'd like to keep countDash as a global variable for whatever reason (although we should reduce global variable use where possible) you can just update it after you update count in the increment function :)